# Waf is unable to find 3rd party library

Tags: waf

I have 2 libraries that exist at /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a and /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.a. My waf script has

```
conf.check_cfg(package='protobuf', args='--cflags --libs', uselib_store="PROTOBUF")
conf.check_cfg(package='grpc++', args='--cflags --libs', uselib_store="GRPC")
```

when waf configure runs, it finds protobuf but says grpc++ isn't found.

```
Checking for 'protobuf' : yes
Checking for 'grpc++' : not found
```

How can it find 1 and not the other? How can I tell waf where to look for the grpc++ lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conf.check_cfg()` use pkg-config files. You probably don't have a `.pc` file for `libgrpc++` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.

In any case, you can define your flags manually (see [wafbook](https://waf.io/book/#_library_interaction_use) §10.3.3):

```py
# arbitrary values :)
conf.env.DEFINES_GRPC = ['HAVE_GRPC']
conf.env.CFLAGS_GRPC = ['-O2']
conf.env.LIB_GRPC = ['m']
conf.env.LIBPATH_GRPC = ['/usr/lib']
conf.env.LINKFLAGS_GRPC = ['-g']
conf.env.INCLUDES_GRPC = ['/opt/lib']
```

The first part a keyword known by waf (list in §10.3.3), the second part `GRPC` is the `uselib_store` name to use (with parameter `use`).

Comment: This ended up being close. It turned out grpc had a dependency on re2 and I was missing an re2 .pc file. After finding the file from the grpc build, I added the pkg_config_path pointing to its location to check_cfg and the command was successful.

Comment: Fine. Good luck with your project!